# What causes some iOS web pages to not continue scrolling when swiping finger is released?

Tags: css, scroll, uiwebview, mobile-safari, hybrid-mobile-app

I have webpages or certain scroll context sections of webpages that do not scroll correctly in mobile Safari and UIWebView. When you are swiping, the normal behavior is for the page to continue scrolling after your finger leaves the screen, and gradually stop depending on how quickly you swiped. On these pages, the page stops scrolling as soon as finger is lifted, resulting in a very stilted-feeling user experience.

- These pages work correctly when using the trackpad on desktop Safari.
- I am not using any libraries that do JS scrolling. I am not listening to scroll events.

One example:

http://parlaywith.me/terms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned you aren't using any libraries to do JS scrolling, but it looks like one of the libraries you're including (Polymer I believe) is taking over scrolling.

To confirm this, use the Safari Web Inspector and disable javascript - you'll see that your sample page will no longer scroll at all.